# page control in flex(like php)

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, mxml

I'm new in flex.
I have a design like this

in one page have two option like this

Hard & soft

when i click hard(option) there will show three option(in php got to another page) like

standard, square & pocket and in the page below BACK(when click this option it will back  previous state(page)) option will be show

When mouse over on any option's this will show its properties in any side of page

when select any one of them it will go next step(page) for more performance.

Soft option will work like hard option.

Please help me with code example or tutorials.

Best regard 
mahedi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manage many pages (aka flex components): I suggest using the "ViewStack" Container; or "TabNavigator" might be easier for flex beginners.

To make the "back button" in the browser (e.g., Internet Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, etc) work correctly, I suggest using the "Browser Manager".

The following tutorials should help with "ViewStack" and "BrowserManager":
www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-snippet-tutorial-view-stack-component
www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-browsermanager-browser-history-and-the-back-button-fun

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your valuable reply.